# Formula for k^k finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

does $\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$ have an explicit formula?
I tried to to write k's in in terms of (e) and imaginary unit, and used Euler formula ($e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta +i\sin\theta$), I also used sine and cosine in terms of (e) and the imaginary unit, But what way ever I do I go back to ($k^k$).
One thing that might help if you know the infinite series representation of $x^n$ 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope, no formula.

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything very helpful.  OEIS gives the sequence as [A001923](https://oeis.org/A001923) and there are some links on that page which might be useful.

Comment: What happens when $k=0$?

Comment: Related: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Peter Foreman, It's a type mistake, k =  1